# How to use OnClick property in asp.net image control for making a image gallery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ms-access, image-gallery

I have developed a website in asp.net which shows pictures of cars with form view control from an Access database. If a user clicks on or places the cursor on that particular ASP image, then I want that image appear in large view. I am trying to use a javascript function, but ASP image doesn't have an OnClick property for calling javascript functions.

Comment: @SubirAdhikari, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0):

The asp.net web control that provides this sort of feature is called the ImageMap perhaps you should use this control instead asp:img

Please see an example on MSDN 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagemap.aspx